# dealing with empty url breaking xml parsing loop

Tags: python, xml, parsing, url, python-3.x

I am writing a code to parse through a bunch of xml files. It basically looks like this:

```
for i in range(0, 20855):
    urlb = str(i)
    url = urla + urlb
    trys=0
    t=0
    while (trys < 3):
        try:
            cfile = UR.urlopen(url)
            trys = 3
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            t=t+1
            print('error at '+str(time.time()-tstart)+' seconds')
            print('typeID = '+str(i))
            print(e.code)
            print(e.read())
            time.sleep (0.1)
            trys=0+t
    tree = ET.parse(cfile)   ##parse xml file
    root = tree.getroot()
    ...do a bunch of stuff with i and the file data
```

I'm having a problem with some of the urls I'm calling not actually containing an xml file which breaks my code. I have a list of all the actual numbers that I use instead of the range shown but i really don't want to go through all 21000 and remove each number that fails. Is there an easier way to get around this? I get an error from the while loop (which i have to deal with timeouts really) that looks like this:

```
b'A non-marketable type was given'
error at 4.321678161621094 seconds
typeID = 31
400
```

So I was thinking there has to be a good way to bail out of that iteration of the for-loop if my while-loop returns three errors but i can't use break. Maybe an if/else-loop under the while-loop that just passes if the t variable is 3?

Comment: the if loop "works" but is obnoxiously slow. is there a way for the error loop to take an action based on a specific error? like could i say if the error code was 400 (i believe thats what its telling me there) then skip that number?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions below you might also want to try parsing with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It can recover from more cases of invalid HTML but is a little slower. If you know that your documents are 100% valid XML you can also look into [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) which is a lot faster and makes handling XML quite nice in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
for i in range(0, 20855):
    url = '%s%d' % (urla, i)
    for trys in range(3):
        try:
            cfile = UR.urlopen(url)
            break
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            print('error at %s seconds' % (time.time()-tstart))
            print('typeID = %i'%i)
            print(e.code)
            print(e.read())
            time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        print "retry failed 3 times"
        continue
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(cfile)   ##parse xml file
    except Exception, e:
        print "cannot read xml"
        print e
        continue
    root = tree.getroot()
    ...do a bunch of stuff with i and the file data
```

Comment: Instead of the over-generalized `except Exception, e`, one should look up which exceptions may occur and then specifically catch them.

Comment: that looks really promising. I have a syntax error with the comma after Exception though. do you know the correct syntax for 3.3? I can't tell from a quick look at the 3.3 exception documents

Comment: found it. the correct syntax for 3.3 would be
    except Exception as e:

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "algorithmic" problem: You can always set an error state (as simple as e.g. `last_iteration_successful = False`) in the while body, then break out of the while body, then check the error state in the for body, and conditionally break out of the for body, too.

Regarding architecture: Prepare your code for all relevant errors that might occur, via proper exception handling with try/except blocks. It might also make sense to define custom Exception types, and then raise them manually. Raising an exception immediately interrupts the current control flow, it could save many `break`s.